# Разница в поведении при перенаправлении стандартного вывода в Python

Tags: python, xml, парсер, сервер, исключения

Пишу небольшой сервер на Python, используя `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. В методе `do_POST` я обрабатываю ошибки и т.к. в случае ошибки, я хочу продолжать слушать порт, но выйти из метода `do_POST`, я ничего лучше не придумал как выбросить исключение после того, как ответ клиенту будет отправлен. Однако поведение при выбросе исключения различно при стандартном выводе в консоль и в файл. Если выбрасывается исключение при выводе в консоль, то сервер выводит исключение в консоль и продолжает слушать канал. Но в коде есть кусок, когда я перенаправляю стандартный вывод в лог:

```
LOG_NAME = 'log.txt'
with open(LOG_NAME, 'w') as log_file:
    sys.stdout = log_file
    sys.stderr = log_file
```

В результате, после выброса исключения сервер прекращает работу с кодом ошибки: `Process finished with exit code 1`. И возникает вопрос: "Почему при выводе в файл, исключения ломают сервер?"

Вот код сервера:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import BaseHTTPServer
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml
import sys
import sqlite3
import traceback

ENCODING = 'utf-8'
NAME_DB = 'ndatabase.db'
LOG_NAME = 'xml.log'
FILENAME_ANSWER = 'new.xml'


class XML:
    @staticmethod
    def parse_request(request):
        try:
            request_element = xml.fromstring(request)
        except xml.ParseError:
            print 'Error: XML declaration not well-formed.'
            return False
        check_results = []
        elements_dict = {element.tag: element for element in request_element}
        tags = ['Count', 'HddTest']
        for tag in tags:
            if tag not in elements_dict:
                print('Error: Expected element: {}'.format(tag))
                return False
        try:
            count = tags[0]
            count_val = int(elements_dict[count].text)
            check_results.append(count_val)
        except ValueError:
            print "Error: Expected int element: <Count></Count>"
            return False
        try:
            hdd_test = tags[1]
            atrib_dict = elements_dict[hdd_test].attrib
            atrib_list = [('ctrl', 'READ'), ('code', int), ('tms', int)]
            ctrl = atrib_list[0][0]
            ctrl_val = atrib_list[0][1]
            if atrib_dict[ctrl] != ctrl_val:
                raise KeyError
        except KeyError:
            print "Error: Expected attribute: ctrl='READ'"
            return False
        try:
            code = atrib_list[1][0]
            code_type = atrib_list[1][1]
            if code in atrib_dict:
                uniq_id = code_type(atrib_dict[code])
                check_results.append((code, uniq_id))
                return check_results
        except ValueError:
            print "Error: Expected int attribute: code"
            return False
        try:
            tms = atrib_list[2][0]
            tms_type = atrib_list[2][1]
            if tms in atrib_dict:
                tms_val = atrib_dict[tms]
                if len(tms_val) != 10:
                    raise ValueError
                unix_time = tms_type(tms_val)
                if unix_time < 0:
                    raise ValueError
                check_results.append((tms, unix_time))
                return check_results
        except ValueError:
            print "Error: Expected int attribute: tms in format DDDDDDDDDD"
            return False
        print "Error: Expected one of attributes: code or tms"
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def create_answer(result):
        data = xml.Element('data')
        _id = unicode(00003072)
        _from = u"маг1_касса136"
        _to = u"маг1"
        tstamp = unicode(1545901294)
        data.attrib = {'type': 'REPLY',
                       'id': _id,
                       'from': _from,
                       'to': _to,
                       'tstamp': tstamp}
        i = 0
        test_columns = ['hddModule', 'testStatus', 'hddFilling', 'hddName', 'hddSerial']
        attr_columns = ['name', 'value', 'thresh', 'type', 'raw_value']
        for test in result[0]:
            hdd_test = xml.Element('HddTest')
            code = test[0]
            hdd_test.attrib = {'ctrl': 'READ',
                               'tms': test[1],
                               'code': unicode(code)}
            for n in range(len(test_columns)):
                sub_element = xml.SubElement(hdd_test, test_columns[n])
                sub_element.text = unicode(test[n + 2])
            for attr in result[1][i:]:
                test_id = attr[1]
                if test_id == code:
                    hdd_attribute = xml.SubElement(hdd_test, 'hddAttributes')
                    hdd_attribute.attrib = {'code': unicode(attr[0])}
                    for n in range(len(attr_columns)):
                        sub_element = xml.SubElement(hdd_attribute, attr_columns[n])
                        sub_element.text = unicode(attr[n + 2])
                    i += 1
                else:
                    break
            data.append(hdd_test)
        '''
        for element in data:
            for child in element:
                if child.tag == 'hddAttributes':
                    print child.attrib['code']
        '''
        tree = xml.ElementTree(data)
        return tree

class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, name_database):
        self.name_database = name_database
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(name_database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def get_tms(self, unix_time, count):
        sql_query = """SELECT min(uniqID)
        FROM test
        WHERE unixtime >= strftime('%s', {}, 'unixepoch')""".format(unix_time)
        self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
        code = self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        if code is None:
            print('Warning: entries later than {} unixtime are not found.'.format(unix_time))
            return False
        return self.get_code(code, count)

    def get_code(self, code, count):
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE {} <= uniqID and uniqID < {}".format(code, code + count)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
            test_entries = self.cursor.fetchall()
            if not test_entries:
                print('Warning: entries with uniqID more than {} are not found.'.format(code))
                return False
            from_to = (test_entries[0][0], test_entries[-1][0])
            sql_query = """SELECT *
            FROM attributes
            WHERE {} <= testID and testID <= {}""".format(from_to[0], from_to[1])
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
            attributes_entries = self.cursor.fetchall()
            return test_entries, attributes_entries
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("Warning: can't make a request '{}'.".format(sql_query))


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def basic_error_send(self, error_code):
        self.send_response(error_code)
        with open(LOG_NAME, 'r') as f:
            text_answer = f.read()
            print text_answer
            self.send_header("Content-length", len(text_answer))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(text_answer)
            self.wfile.close()
            raise Exception(text_answer)

    def do_POST(self):
        LOG_NAME = 'log.txt'
        with open(LOG_NAME, 'w') as log_file:
            #sys.stdout = log_file
            #sys.stderr = log_file
            content_type = self.headers.gettype()
            if content_type != 'text/xml':
                print 'Expected content-type: text/xml'
                self.basic_error_send(404)
            content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))
            request = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            parse_results = XML.parse_request(request)
            if not parse_results:
                self.basic_error_send(404)

            db = Database(NAME_DB)

            count = parse_results[0]
            if parse_results[1][0] == 'code':
                code = parse_results[1][1]
                db_result = db.get_code(code, count)
            elif parse_results[1][0] == 'tms':
                tms = parse_results[1][1]
                db_result = db.get_tms(tms, count)
            else:
                self.send_response(500)
                text_answer = 'Inform your provider about this problem.'
                self.wfile.write(text_answer)
                raise Exception(text_answer)
            if not db_result:
                self.basic_error_send(404)

            tree = XML.create_answer(db_result)
            with open(FILENAME_ANSWER, 'w+') as f:
                tree.write(f, encoding=ENCODING)
                answer = f.read()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-length", len(answer))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(answer)
            self.wfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 8008), RequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Запускается сервер с помощью shell скрипта:

```
exec curl -H 'content-type: text/xml' \
    --data "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1251'?>
<data type='REQUEST' id='00003072' from='маг1' to='маг1_касса136' tstamp='741009671'>
    <HddTest ctrl='READ' tms='741009671' code='5'></HddTest>
    <Count> 100 </Count>
</data>" \
    http://localhost:8008
```

То есть по сути отправляется XML запрос, после чего формируется XML ответ.
Вот ссылка (ЯД) на базу данных (`'ndatabase.db'`), которая используется в работе:
https://yadi.sk/d/rwmb_GEgwKRzOA

Comment: А права есть на запись в ту папку куда вы лог пытаетесь писать?

Comment: Да, с правами всё в порядке.

Comment: Я добавил код самого сервера и все данные, необходимые для его запсука.

Comment: Вы как минимум не возвращаете оригинальные объекты sys.stdout и sys.stderr после завершения do_POST, и в итоге сервер пытается писать логи в **закрытый** файл, что неизбежно завершится ошибкой

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что в блоке         `with open(LOG_NAME, 'w') as log_file:
            sys.stdout = log_file
            sys.stderr = log_file` происходит не безопасное присваивание? Т.е. в случае исключения теряется вывод в консоль, верно?

Comment: В случае исключения завершается блок with, файл закрывается и информация об исключении пытается записаться в закрытый файл, что естественно не удаётся